# How do I use in input from one function in another?

Tags: python, python-3.x

So I'm writing a higher or lower game and I am experimenting with functions. I have a couple functions in my code but I need 2 in particular to kind of work with each other in order for my code to run properly (my code isn't finished yet so there are still a lot of mechanics I need to add).

```
def winner(opponent1, opponent2):

  opponent1_flwrs = opponent1['follower_count']
  opponent2_flwrs = opponent2['follower_count']
  score = 0

  if opponent1_flwrs > opponent2_flwrs:
    if higher_or_lower == "A" or higher_or_lower == "a":
      score += 1
      return "You're right! Current score: " + score
    else:
      clear()
      print(art.logo)
      return "Sorry, that's wrong. Final score: " + score
  elif opponent2_flwrs > opponent1_flwrs:
    if higher_or_lower == "B" or higher_or_lower == "b":
      score += 1
      return "You're right! Current score: " + score
    else:
      clear()
      print(art.logo)
      return "Sorry, that's wrong. Final score: " + score

def game(opponent1, opponent2:
  """
  Contains the code necessary for the game to begin and will continue to execute 
  as long as the user is the winner
  """
  print(art.logo)
  print(f"Compare A: {opponent1['name']}, a {opponent1['description']}, "
        f"from {opponent1['country']}")
  print(art.vs)
  print(f"Against B: {opponent2['name']}, a {opponent2['description']}, "
        f"from {opponent2['country']}")
  higher_or_lower = input("Who has more followers A or B? ")
```

I have a file that contains the data so the values for `opponent1`, `opponent2`, and `opponent1_flwrs`, `opponent2_flwrs` are taken from that data.

I want the `higher_or_lower` input from the game function to be able to do the same thing in the winner function and have the same value if that makes sense. Also later on I'm going to add a `while` loop that's going to call on these functions continuously until the user has lost.

Comment: What you say you want to do isn't clear. Nor is what is preventing you from doing it.

Comment: The usual way to pass data between functions is via arguments.

Answer (score 0):

firstable, sorry for the bad English, but I think that you can just pass the higher_or_lower variable to the winner function like this:

```
def winner(opponent1, opponent2, chosen_option, current_score):
  chosen_option= chosen_option== 'a'
  correct_option= opponent1['follower_count']> opponent2['follower_count']
  
  if chosen_option== correct_option:
    score += 1
    return "You're right! Current score: " + score
  else:
    clear()
    print(art.logo)
    return "Sorry, that's wrong. Final score: " + score

def game(opponent1, opponent2, score):
  """
  Contains the code necessary for the game to begin and will continue to execute as long as the user is the winner
  """
  print(art.logo)
  print(f"Compare A: {opponent1['name']}, a {opponent1['description']}, from {opponent1['country']}")
  print(art.vs)
  print(f"Against B: {opponent2['name']}, a {opponent2['description']}, from {opponent2['country']}")
  higher_or_lower = input("Who has more followers, A or B? ").lower()
  winner(opponent1, opponent2, higher_or_lower)
```

in the main loop you have to declare the score variable so you don't reset it every time you call the function

Comment: I tried also to clean a little bit your code, but I think as @martineau said, the simpliest way to make functions interact between eachother is by passing arguments

Comment: also I would ckeck the input, because the code is going to break if the user types in something different from a and b